# Loop through subfolders

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert images into multiple Excel files. It works for the first file and then goes unresponsive on the second file or ends.

I have a main folder with subfolders. Each subfolder contains a single Excel file and multiple images. I want to open the Excel file in each subfolder and insert the images from the same file.

I think the issue is with my loop in the first Sub.

```vb
Sub InsertImagesIntoPhotoLog()
    On Error Resume Next ' Automatically dismiss error messages
    
    Dim mainFolderPath As String
    Dim subfolderPath As String
    Dim imagePath As String
    Dim mergedCells As Variant
    Dim cellRange As Range
    Dim imageIndex As Integer
    
    ' Set the main folder path
    mainFolderPath = "Y:\Kansas\130800S\130882.00_KCMO_2022_Biennials\Office_Docs\Reports\Short Span Inspection_Files\Caleb's Short Spans\Sample\"
    
    ' Define the merged cell addresses
    mergedCells = Array("B10:G26", "I10:P26", "B29:G45", "I29:P45", "B49:G65", "I49:P65", "B68:G84", "I68:P84", "B88:G104", "I88:P104", _
                        "B107:G123", "I107:P123", "B127:G143", "I127:P143", "B146:G162", "I146:P162", "B166:G182", "I166:P182", _
                        "B185:G201", "I185:P201", "B205:G221", "I205:P221", "B224:G240", "I224:P240", "B244:G260", "I244:P260", _
                        "B263:G279", "I263:P279", "B283:G299", "I283:P299", "B302:G318", "I302:P318", "B322:G338", "I322:P338", _
                        "B341:G357", "I341:P357", "B361:G377", "I361:P377", "B380:G396", "I380:P396", "B400:G416", "I400:P416", _
                        "B419:G435", "I419:P435", "B439:G455", "I439:P455", "B458:G474", "I458:P474")
    
    ' Get the first subfolder in the main folder
    subfolderPath = Dir(mainFolderPath & "*", vbDirectory)
    
    ' Loop through each subfolder in the main folder
    Do While subfolderPath <> ""
        ' Check if the subfolder is a folder and not "." or ".."
        If (GetAttr(mainFolderPath & subfolderPath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory And subfolderPath <> "." And subfolderPath <> ".." Then
            ' Set the path to the current subfolder
            subfolderPath = mainFolderPath & subfolderPath & "\"
            
            ' Get the first Excel file in the subfolder
            imagePath = Dir(subfolderPath & "*.xlsm") ' Modify file extension if needed
            
            ' Check if an Excel file exists in the subfolder
            If imagePath <> "" Then
                ' Set the path to the current Excel file
                imagePath = subfolderPath & imagePath
                
                ' Open the workbook
                Dim wb As Workbook
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(imagePath)
                
                ' Check if the workbook opened successfully
                If Not wb Is Nothing Then
                    ' Set the worksheet where you want to insert the images in the opened workbook
                    Dim photoLog As Worksheet
                    Set photoLog = wb.Worksheets("KCMO_EBIF_22_PhotoLog")
                    
                    ' Count the number of images in the current subfolder
                    Dim imageCount As Integer
                    imageCount = CountImagesInFolder(subfolderPath)
                    
                    ' Check if the number of images matches the number of merged cells
                    If imageCount = UBound(mergedCells) + 1 Then
                        imageIndex = 1
                        
                        ' Loop through each merged cell address
                        For Each mergedCell In mergedCells
                            ' Construct the merged cell range
                            Set cellRange = photoLog.Range(mergedCell)
                            
                            ' Get the image file path
                            Dim imageFilePath As String
                            imageFilePath = GetImageFilePath(subfolderPath, "Image" & imageIndex & ".jpg") ' Modify image file naming convention if needed
                            
                            If Len(Dir(imageFilePath)) > 0 Then
                                ' Insert the image into the current cell
                                InsertImageIntoCell imageFilePath, cellRange, photoLog
                                
                                ' Increment the image index
                                imageIndex = imageIndex + 1
                            End If
                        Next mergedCell
                        
                        ' Save and close the workbook
                        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        
        ' Get the next subfolder in the main folder
        subfolderPath = Dir
    Loop
    
    Exit Sub ' Skip error handling
End Sub

Sub InsertImageIntoCell(ByVal imagePath As String, ByVal cellRange As Range, ByVal photoLog As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next ' Continue execution in case of error
    
    With cellRange
        ' Clear the contents of the cell
        .ClearContents
        .MergeCells = False
        
        ' Center the image in the cell
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        
        ' Insert the image
        Dim picture As Shape
        Set picture = photoLog.Shapes.AddPicture(fileName:=imagePath, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                                                 Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height)
        
        If Not picture Is Nothing Then
            With picture
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .ShapeRange.Height = .TopLeftCell.Height
                .ShapeRange.Width = .TopLeftCell.Width
                .Top = .TopLeftCell.Top
                .Left = .TopLeftCell.Left
            End With
        End If
    End With
    
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Disable error handling
End Sub

Function CountImagesInFolder(ByVal folderPath As String) As Integer
    ' Count the number of image files in the specified folder
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    
    ' Get the first image file in the folder
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.jpg") ' Modify file extension if needed
    
    ' Loop through the files and count the image files
    Do Until fileName = ""
        count = count + 1
        fileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    CountImagesInFolder = count
End Function

Function GetImageFilePath(ByVal folderPath As String, ByVal fileName As String) As String
    ' Get the file path of the image in the specified folder with the given file name
    GetImageFilePath = folderPath & fileName
End Function
```

I tried adding delays and other optimizations.

Comment: The first step should be deleting `On Error Resume Next`. Its scope should be as narrow as possible, and definitely not a whole function. Maybe, instead of hanging, you will get an error message, and you will know what to do.

Comment: You cannot nest calls to `Dir()`.  Each loop needs to be completed before beginning another.  Try (eg) collecting all the subfolder paths in a Collection and then looping over that collection to find the files in each subfolder.

Comment: When working with multiple folders, I use - and I reccommend that you try using - the [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object). Once you have gotten the parent folder as an object using `GetFolder` you can loop through the `Subfolders` and `Files` collections. Its much less messy than `Dir`, in my opinion.

Comment: An Addendum to Tim Williams comment to clarify Dir. Dir with input parameter starts a completely new search for file/directory. Dir alone use the same search parameter for finding next occurence. Anytime you define a new Dir(withpar) it drop the old parameter and start with the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but here's one way to solve the "nested Dir" issue:

```vb
Sub InsertImagesIntoPhotoLog()
    'use const for fixed values
    Const NUM_PICS As Long = 48  '# of pics on the sheet
    Const MAIN_FOLDER As String = "Y:\Kansas\130800S\130882.00_KCMO_2022_Biennials\Office_Docs\" & _
                                  "Reports\Short Span Inspection_Files\Caleb's Short Spans\Sample\"
    
    Dim subfolderPath, subfolderPaths As Collection
    Dim imagePath As String, imagePaths As Collection, excelPaths As Collection
    Dim wb As Workbook, photoLog As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, rngPic As Range, i As Long, rowOffset As Long
    
    Set subfolderPaths = AllSubFolders(MAIN_FOLDER)
    
    For Each subfolderPath In subfolderPaths
        Set excelPaths = MatchedFiles(CStr(subfolderPath), "*.xlsm")
        If excelPaths.count > 0 Then 'found at least one xlsm ?
            
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(excelPaths(1))
            Set photoLog = wb.Worksheets("KCMO_EBIF_22_PhotoLog")
            Set c = photoLog.Range("B10") 'top-left cell of first block
            rowOffset = 19                'first row offset
            
            Set imagePaths = MatchedFiles(CStr(subfolderPath), "Image*.jpg")
            If imagePaths.count = NUM_PICS Then
                For i = 1 To NUM_PICS
                    Set rngPic = c.Resize(17, IIf(c.Column = 2, 6, 8)) 'set height/width
                    imagePath = subfolderPath & "Image" & i & ".jpg"
                    
                    If IsInCollection(imagePaths, imagePath) Then 'have expected image file?
                        InsertImageIntoCell imagePath, rngPic
                    Else
                        Debug.Print "Missing file 'Image" & i & _
                                ".jpg' in subfolder '" & subfolderPath & "'"
                        'what to do in case of a missing file?
                    End If
                    
                    'set the position for the next insert
                    If c.Column = 2 Then
                        Set c = c.Offset(0, 7)                  'move right
                    Else
                        Set c = c.Offset(rowOffset, -7)         'move left and down
                        rowOffset = IIf(rowOffset = 19, 20, 19) 'toggle row offset between 19 and 20
                    End If
                Next i       'next image
            End If           'image count OK
            wb.Close True    'close with save
        End If               'got an Excel file
    Next subfolderPath

End Sub

Sub InsertImageIntoCell(imagePath As String, cellRange As Range)
    Dim picture As Shape
    With cellRange
        .ClearContents
        .MergeCells = False
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        Set picture = .Worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
            fileName:=imagePath, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
            Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Width:=-1, Height:=-1)
    End With
        
    With picture
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Height = cellRange.Height
        .Width = cellRange.Width
    End With
End Sub

'is value `v` in collection `col`?
Function IsInCollection(col As Collection, v) As Boolean
    Dim el
    For Each el In col
        If el = v Then
            IsInCollection = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next el
End Function

'return a collection of all subfodlers of `path`
Function AllSubFolders(path As String) As Collection
    Dim f
    Set AllSubFolders = New Collection
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    f = Dir(path, vbDirectory)
    Do While Len(f) <> 0
        If f <> "." And f <> ".." Then
            If (GetAttr((path & f)) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then _
                                      AllSubFolders.Add path & f & "\"
        End If
        f = Dir()
    Loop
End Function

'return a collection of all files at `path` which match `pattern`
Function MatchedFiles(path As String, pattern As String) As Collection
    Dim f
    Set MatchedFiles = New Collection
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    f = Dir(path & pattern)
    Do While Len(f) <> 0
        MatchedFiles.Add path & f 'returning the full path
        f = Dir()
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please flag as Accepted, to help anyone else coming along later with a similar issue.

Comment: The code successfully loops through all of the excel files in the subfolder, but no images were inserted when I go and open the files. All I modified was correcting the worksheet name.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I modified the code to be able to insert images with unique names and my code is running.